# Importing data from HTML table to highcharts

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts, datatable

I have for a a few days been trying to write a code using highcharts. The point of the code is that I want to be able to enter data into a table and then have the charts update accordingly. I haven't made the update component yet, as I am stuck at getting the data from the table to the charts. They either stop working entirely, turn transparent or parts disappear.

My HTML:

```
<body>
<table border="1" style="width:100%" id='datatable1'>
<tr>
<th colspan="1" style="width: 200px;"></th>
<th colspan="1">Build 1</th>
<th colspan="1">Build 2</th>  
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Power</td>
  <td contenteditable='true' id='BP1' ><b>0</b></td>
  <td contenteditable='true' id='BP2'><b>0</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Precision</td>
<td contenteditable='true' id='BPr1'><b>0</b></td>
<td contenteditable='true' id='BPr2'><b>0</b></td>  
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Vitality</td>
<td contenteditable='true' id='BV1'><b>0</b></td>
<td contenteditable='true' id='BV2'><b>0</b></td>  
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Toughness</td>
<td contenteditable='true' id='BT1'><b>0</b></td>
<td contenteditable='true' id='BT2'><b>0</b></td>  
</tr>
</table>

<div class="spacer" style="height: 20px;"></div>    

<table border="1" style="width:100%" class="zebra" id='datatable2'>
<tr>
<th colspan="1" style="width: 200px;"></th>
<th colspan="1">Build 1</th>
<th colspan="1">Build 2</th>  
</tr>   
<tr>
<td>Ferocity</td>
<td contenteditable='true' id='BF1'><b>0</b></td>
<td contenteditable='true' id='BF2'><b>0</b></td>   
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Condition Damage</td>
<td contenteditable='true' id='BC1'><b>0</b></td>
<td contenteditable='true' id='BC2'><b>0</b></td>  
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Healing Power</td>
<td contenteditable='true' id='BH1'><b>0</b></td>
<td contenteditable='true' id='BH2'><b>0</b></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body> 

<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="Primary" class="chart"></div>
<div class="spacer"style="height:20px;"></div>
<div id="Secondary" class="chart"></div>
```

The reason all the editable cells have an id is because my first thought was to direct to the data in the individual cell, but I was not able to make it work.

My JS:

```
             $(function () {

//Primary:   Power, Precision, Vitality, Toughness
//Secondary: Ferocity, Condition Damage, Healing Power
$('#Primary').highcharts({         

    chart: {
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
        plotBorderWidth: 0,
        plotShadow: false,
        polar: true,
        type: 'line'
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Primary Attributes',
        x: -80
    },

    pane: {
        size: '100%'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Power', 'Precision', 'Vitality', 'Toughness'],
        tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
        lineWidth: 0
    },

    **yAxis: {
        gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
        lineWidth: 0,
        min: 0**
    },

    tooltip: {
        shared: true,
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}: <b>{point.y:,.0f}</b><br/>'
    },

    legend: {
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 70,
        layout: 'vertical'
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    **series: [{
        name: 'Build 1',
        data: [0, 150, 680, 600],
        pointPlacement: 'on'
    }, {
        name: 'Build 2',
        data: [100, 170, 1045, 400],
        pointPlacement: 'on'**
    }]

});



// Chart 2
$('#Secondary').highcharts({

    chart: {
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
        plotBorderWidth: 0,
        plotShadow: false,
        polar: true,
        type: 'line'
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Secondary Attributes',
        x: -80
    },

    pane: {
        size: '100%'
    },

    **xAxis: {
        categories: ['Condition', 'Healing Power', 'Ferocity'],
        tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
        lineWidth: 0**
    },

    yAxis: {
        gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
        lineWidth: 0,
        min: 0
    },

    tooltip: {
        shared: true,
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}: <b>{point.y:,.0f}</b><br/>'
    },

    legend: {
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 70,
        layout: 'vertical'
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    **series: [{
        name: 'Build 1',
        data: [0, 150, 680],
        pointPlacement: 'on'
    }, {
        name: 'Build 2',
        data: [100, 170, 1045],
        pointPlacement: 'on'**
    }]

});
```

The JS consists of two charts - "Primary" is supposed to use the data from the table with id="datatable1" and "Secondary" is supposed to use the data from the table called id="datatable2". They are both Spider Web Charts.  The parts in bold are the current data (placeholder).

I have tried using the following method, recommended from highcharts for HTML tables, but I just can't make it work with Spider Web Charts.

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    data: {
        table: 'datatable'
    },
```

Everything above is shown in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zipdz/477nt4zh/1/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably the problem with data is using `<b>..</b>` tags - Highcharts tries to parse this string as number and `parseFloat()` is returning NaN. Remove them and `data.js` module should work without issues.

Regarding updating data on change, I would add extra info to each of the rows, for example:

```
<tr>
  <td>Power</td>
  <td contenteditable='true' id='BP1' chart="0" series="0" point="0">0</td>
  <td contenteditable='true' id='BP2' chart="0" series="1" point="0">0</td>
</tr>
```

Where:

- `chart="0"` - index of the chart (0 or 1)
- `series="0"` - index of the seres/building (0 or 1)
- `point="0"` - index of the point in series (or we can call it row-index)

Now, just attach event to update correct points:

```
$('#datatable1 td[contenteditable=true]').on("input", function (e) {
    var $self = $(this),
        chart = $self.attr("chart"),
        series = $self.attr("series"),
        point = $self.attr("point"),
        value = parseFloat($self.text());

    if (!isNaN(value)) { // prevent from setting "asdafd" etc. strings - only numbers are accepted
        Highcharts.charts[chart].series[series].points[point].update(value);
    }
});
```

Now, see working demo (for the first chart): http://jsfiddle.net/477nt4zh/2/

Comment: Many thanks, that did the trick. I will try and apply it to the rest of my work.